# ProgressDialog not dismissing in onPostExecute() android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have read all solutions for the same question, but did not seem to find a answer.
I have a ProgressDialog which I am showing in the `onPreExecute()` of a AsyncTask. It does not dismiss after the doInBackground() is finished.

Here is my code:-

Main.java

```
    case R.id.action_refresh:

        new RefreshItems().execute();
        return true;




private class RefreshItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    ProgressDialog refDialog ;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    List<News> updatedList;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(refDialog!=null && refDialog.isShowing() && refDialog.isIndeterminate())
            refDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        refDialog =  ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "", "Please wait", true, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            updatedList = new GetList().execute(items).get();
            fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl,encodedAccountName,deviceAuthKey,usersname,avatarUrl, fullName,getApplicationContext(),updatedList);


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Kindly give a reason for a downvote

Comment: is GetList another asynctask?

Comment: Maybe you show another progress in the other AsyncTask? Still the documentation states that's wrong to start an AsyncTask from another AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
refDialog.isIndeterminate()
```

You are not measuring something so it will return false, so it is not dismissing your dialog.

**solution:**

remove it in your if statement

```
if(refDialog!=null && refDialog.isShowing())
```

Also remove **this**:

```
super.onPostExecute(result);
```

you dont need the default `onPostExecute`;

**Edit:**

**problem 2:**

```
ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "", "Please wait", true, false);
```

you set the cancelable to `false` which mean you can not cancel it upon dismissing.

change your showing of dialog to this:

```
refDialog =  ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "", "Please wait")
```

Comment: @user3713706 are you sure onpostexecute is executed?? can you Log.d on it.

Comment: you are right.. onPostExecute() is not being executed. What should I do?

Comment: @user3713706 dont call another synctask in doinbackground it is already on different thread so you put the code what is inside that inner asynctask in your doinbackground

Comment: I moved the progressdialog code to the other AsyncTask and it works fine.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your below condition is becoming wrong in any manner,

```
if(refDialog!=null && refDialog.isShowing() && refDialog.isIndeterminate())
```

Just remove that condition and simply dismiss your dialog,

```
refDialog.dismiss();
```

Or,

Check your condition, that in which case its becoming wrong.

Comment: Had tried it at the very beginning and it gave me the same results

Answer (score 0):

remove `if(refDialog!=null && refDialog.isShowing())` from `onPostExecute` and it will work
if you really need to know if it is showing you can create a `boolean visible=false;` in the class set it true on preExecute ant check it on Post Exec

Answer (score 0):

Make dialog field `refDialog` static and then try it

```
public static ProgressDialog refDialog ;
```